# Making a telegram app using cloudRail, how do I listen to the response from the user?

Tags: node.js, telegram, cloudrail

I am making a little app for telegram using CloudRail. This is my node.js server. The node.js sends message to a telegram user when it receives a POST request of kind "sendMessage". But I also want to be able to receive the responses that users sends. How do I listen to the responses the user makes?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const cloudrail = require("cloudrail-si");
cloudrail.Settings.setKey("pass");

const service = new cloudrail.services.Telegram(
    null,
    "botkey",
    "webhook"
);

function sendMessage(user,message){
    service.sendMessage(
    user,
    message,
        (error, result) => {
            if(error){ console.log("hubo un error");}
            // Check for potential error and use the result
        }
    );
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post("/",function(req,res,next){
    service.parseReceivedMessages(
        httpRequest: stream.Readable,
        (error, result) => {
            sendMessage("219148418","esta es mi respuesta");
            // Check for potential error and use the result
        }
    )
    if(req.method ==="POST" && req.body.kind != undefined && req.body.kind=="postMessage"){
        var user_id = req.body.user_id;
        var message = req.body.message;
        sendMessage(user_id, message);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

The **[parseReceivedMessages](https://cloudrail.com/integrations/interfaces/Messaging;serviceIds=Telegram;platformId=Nodejs;interfaceId=Messaging;interfaceFunctionId=Messaging-parseReceivedMessages)** receieves **type Message** which is a response from the user.

See the example:
https://github.com/CloudRail/cloudrail-si-node-sdk/blob/master/examples/unified-messaging/index.js